# Apache/Mongrel/Redmine installation problem (VirtualHost/ProxyPass)

Tags: virtualhost, ruby-on-rails, apache-2.2, redmine, mongrel

I am installing Redmine as per this step-by-step instruction: http://justnotes.co.cc/2010/02/11/how-to-install-redmine-on-ubuntu/

I am using Ubuntu 10.04.1, Apache 2.2.14, Mongrel 1.1.5.

On the VirtualHost configuration stage, I am using this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myserver.lv

    ProxyPass /redmine/ http://localhost:8000/
    ProxyPassReverse /redmine/ http://localhost:8000
    ProxyPreserveHost on

    <Proxy *>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
</VirtualHost>
```

But, when I direct my browser to `http://<my-server's-ip>/redmine/` what I see is not the redmine web application but "Index of /redmine" with, well, index of the files from the root directory of Redmine.

Any idea how to fix that?

P.S. Tried removing the VirtualHost stuff alltogether and instead adding the following simple clauses to apache2.conf:

```
<Proxy *>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPass /redmine/ http://localhost:8000/
ProxyPassReverse /redmine/ http://localhost:8000/

ProxyPreserveHost on
```

As a result, the behavior changes! Now `http://<my-server's-ip>/redmine/` produces the source code of the Redmine's start page, so it is served, but apparently not rendered. At the same time, still, `http://<my-server's-ip>:8000/` works perfectly fine, so Mongrel is serving the Redmine application as it should, it's just that something is wrong with my VirtualHost/proxying clauses in the .conf file.

Answer (score 1):

When you define a virtual host, you must use the given `ServerName` in your browser. Otherwise Apache will render the default virtual host (which may or may not be the one you want). So you should connect to `http://myserver.lv/redmine/` instead of `http://<your-server's-ip>/redmine/`.

I'm not sure why the source code is delivered. The proxy may replace the `Content-type` header, but it would be weird.

You may consider [Phusion Passenger](http://www.modrails.com/install.html). It's very easy to install and setup, and you wouldn't have the extra Mongrel process to manage.

Your Apache configuration would look like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName myserver.lv
  DocumentRoot /path_to_redmine/public
</VirtualHost>
```